# New dota2 ranks

Tags: dota-2

Hi few days ago started new dota2 season, they add some new feature as percents, can you please tell me what this percents means, and how it works with ranks?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how close you are to the next medal, in your case you only need 10% more to rank up.